# Create matrix with N-4 rows and N-2 columns

Tags: matlab

Would you give me any comments on this question? I need to create a matrix in Matlab, following the description below:

for a given `N` and three values `a`, `b` and `c`. I want to create a (N-4)x(N-2) matrix, e.g. for `N=8`

```
    a     b     c     0     0     0

    0     a     b     c     0     0

    0     0     a     b     c     0

    0     0     0     a     b     c
```

Thanks a Lot

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this but its to far from the result: `diag(a*ones(N-2,1),0)+ b*diag(ones(N-3,1),1)+ c*diag(cte/4*ones(N-4,1),2)`

Comment: Put it in the question and state a comment on why it doesn't solve your problem. That would make the question more clear

Comment: the problem is that the function diag give a diagonal matrix which is not the case here, so   either there is another function fon nondiagonal matrix, which I think the best way or I need to delete the last two rows but I don't know how because I'm new in Matlab

Comment: To delete the last two rows, you could use `X(end-1:end,:)=[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to create is a [toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). One you know the name, it's simple.

```
%construct the first row
row=zeros(N-2,1);
row(1:3)=[a,b,c];
%construct the first column
col=zeros(N-4,1);
col(1)=a;
%call the function
toeplitz(col,row)
```

Result with `a=4;b=2;c=3;N=8;`

```
ans =

     4     2     3     0     0     0
     0     4     2     3     0     0
     0     0     4     2     3     0
     0     0     0     4     2     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve using the identity matrix function `eye()` and some matrix concatenation:

```matlab
N = 8;

a = 1;
b = 2;
c = 3;

a_I = [zeros(N-4, 0), a*eye(N-4), zeros(N-4, 2)];
b_I = [zeros(N-4, 1), b*eye(N-4), zeros(N-4, 1)];
c_I = [zeros(N-4, 2), c*eye(N-4), zeros(N-4, 0)];

X = a_I + b_I + c_I
```

Which produces the output

```
X =
     1     2     3     0     0     0
     0     1     2     3     0     0
     0     0     1     2     3     0
     0     0     0     1     2     3
```

You can also make it slightly more general and let the scalars `a`, `b` and `c` be contained in a vector:

```matlab
N = 8;

v = [1 2 3];

X = zeros(N-4, N-2);
for ii = 1:length(v)
    X = X + [zeros(N-4, ii-1), v(ii)*eye(N-4), zeros(N-4, length(v)-ii)];
end
```

Which produces the same output.

Answer (score 0):

try this fully vectorized function:

```
function b=bandmat(a, N, M)
% license: CC-BY
% example: bandmat([1,2,3],4,6)
b=a(:).';
b(M+1)=0;
b=repmat(b,1,N);
b=reshape(b(1:end-N),M,N).';
```